# PostgreSQL: Pass table as argument in function

Tags: postgresql, functions, datatypes

I am discovering `TYPE` in PostgreSQL. I have a `TABLE TYPE` that some table must respect (interface). For example:

```
CREATE TYPE dataset AS(
    ChannelId INTEGER
   ,GranulityIdIn INTEGER
   ,GranulityId INTEGER
   ,TimeValue TIMESTAMP
   ,FloatValue FLOAT
   ,Status BIGINT
   ,QualityCodeId INTEGER
   ,DataArray FLOAT[]
   ,DataCount BIGINT
   ,Performance FLOAT
   ,StepCount INTEGER
   ,TableRegClass regclass
   ,Tags TEXT[]
   ,WeightedMean FLOAT
   ,MeanData FLOAT
   ,StdData FLOAT
   ,MinData FLOAT
   ,MaxData FLOAT
   ,MedianData FLOAT
   ,Percentiles FLOAT[]
);
```

I can create table using this template with:

```
CREATE TABLE test OF dataset;
```

I have seen many options in the [API](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-createtype.html), but I am a little lost. I would like to know if it is possible to assign this type to function `INPUT/OUTPUT` parameters.

Let say that I have a `FUNCTION` called `process` that receives a sample of records from a dataset `TABLE` `source`, processes them and then returns a `TABLE` `sink` with the same `TYPE`.

That is I would like to know if it is possible to create a `TYPE` that behaves like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION process(
    input dataset
) RETURNS dataset
AS ...
```

And that can be called like this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    source, process(input := source) AS sink;
```

I wonder that it is possible with PostgreSQL, and ask how to do so. Does anyone of you know?

---

Here is a MWE of what I am trying to do:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS source;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS process(dataset);
DROP TYPE dataset;

CREATE TYPE dataset AS (
    id INTEGER
   ,t  TIMESTAMP
   ,x  FLOAT
);


CREATE TABLE source OF dataset;
ALTER TABLE source ADD PRIMARY KEY(Id);
INSERT INTO source VALUES
    (1, '2016-01-01 00:00:00', 10.0)
   ,(2, '2016-01-01 00:30:00', 11.0)
   ,(3, '2016-01-01 01:00:00', 12.0)
   ,(4, '2016-01-01 01:30:00',  9.0)
   ;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION process(
    _source dataset
)
RETURNS SETOF dataset
AS
$BODY$
SELECT * FROM source;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE SQL;

SELECT * FROM process(source);
```

But it does not succeed, it is like source is perceived as a column instead of a `SETOF RECORDS` with the type of dataset.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The parameter `_source` in the MWE (minimal working example) is not referenced anywhere. The identifier `source` in the function body has no leading underscore and is interpreted as constant table name independently.

But it would not work like this anyway. SQL only allows to parameterize *values* in DML statements. See:

- [Error when setting n_distinct using a plpgsql variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36025963/939860)

#### Solution

You can still make it work using dynamic SQL with `EXECUTE` in a plpgsql function:

```
CREATE TYPE dataset AS (id integer, t timestamp, x float);

CREATE TABLE source OF dataset (PRIMARY KEY(Id));  -- add constraints in same command

INSERT INTO source VALUES
    (1, '2016-01-01 00:00:00', 10.0)
   ,(2, '2016-01-01 00:30:00', 11.0);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION process(_tbl regclass)
  RETURNS SETOF dataset AS
$func$
BEGIN
RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 'SELECT * FROM ' || _tbl;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT * FROM process('source');  -- table name as string literal
```

See:

- [Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10711349/939860)

Or [search](https://dba.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bplpgsql%5D%20%5Bdynamic-sql%5D%20regclass) for related questions and answers on site.

To make it work for *any* given table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION process2(_tbl anyelement)
  RETURNS SETOF anyelement AS
$func$
BEGIN
RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 'SELECT * FROM ' || pg_typeof(_tbl);
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT * FROM process2(NULL::source);  -- note the call syntax!!
```

Detailed explanation:

- [Refactor a PL/pgSQL function to return the output of various SELECT queries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11751557/4632019)

Comment: Thanks for answering. Il will check  it in few hours. Just to know before testing, is your solution accepting to receive rows from as `SELECT`. I mean `SELECT * FROM process((SELECT * FROM source WHERE cond))`.

Comment: @j: No, you pass a table *name*. There is no way to pass a table itself (no table variable). There are several ways around it. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27853965/939860 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/31167928/939860. To work on the result of a query I would use a cursor or a temporary table ...

Answer (score 11):

This will do what you want **without** needing any **dynamic SQL**:

```
drop table if exists source cascade;
drop function if exists process(dataset) cascade;
drop type if exists dataset cascade;

create type dataset as (
    id integer
   ,t  timestamp
   ,x  float
);

create table source of dataset;
alter table source add primary key(id);
insert into source values
   (1, '2016-01-01 00:00:00', 10.0)
 , (2, '2016-01-01 00:30:00', 11.0)
;

create or replace function process(
    x_source dataset[]
)
returns setof dataset
as
$body$
select * from unnest(x_source);
$body$
language sql;

select *
from
  process(
    array(
      select
        row(id, t, x)::dataset
      from source
    )
  );
```

As far as I can tell (after googeling extensivly, because I had the same problem) you can't pass a table directly to a function.

However, as shown, you can transform a table into an array `[]` of a custom type that consists of several basic types (similar to a table definition).

Then you can pass that array and unnest it back into a table once you are in the function.